# Why am I getting a Runtime Error when comparing two columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a macro that should compare two columns in two different cells. It worked at first when I tested it. (Please ignore the german notes)

Both worksheets have 8 columns but I just want to compare the first ones with each other. I have marked the line where I get a

> run time error 424

Can anyone help?

```
'Objekte festlegen
Dim j As Integer
Dim d1 As Object
Dim d2 As Object
Dim d3 As Object
Dim e As Range
Dim shA As Worksheet
Dim shB As Worksheet

Set d1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d3 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set shA = Worksheets(Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
Set shB = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1)

'Füge ICM Nummern des alten Tabellenblattes Objekten zu
With shB
    For Each e In .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row).Value
        d1(e) = True
        d2(e) = True
    Next e
End With

'Neue und alte ICM Nummern bestimmen
With shA
```

> For Each e In .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count,
>   2).End(3).Row).Value

```
        If (d2(e)) * (d1.exists(e)) Then d1.Remove e
        If Not d2(e) Then d3(e) = True
    Next e
```

> ```
> 'Bestimme Anzahl zu erstellender Zeilen
> If d1.Count > d3.Count Then
> Set j = d1.Count
> Else:
> Set j = d3.Count
> End If
> ```

```
'Füge Zellen ein
Range("1:1").Resize(j).Insert Shift:=xlDown, Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

'Objekte transponieren und einfügen in aktuelles Tabellenblatte unter ICM Abzug
On Error Resume Next
    .Cells(1, 10).Resize(d1.Count) = Application.Transpose(d1.keys)
    .Cells(1, 11).Resize(d3.Count) = Application.Transpose(d3.keys)
On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop through a `Range`, not `Value`.

Also, you need to qualify your `Cells` and `Rows.Count` with `With shA`, by adding the `.` as a prefix.

Change:

```
For Each e In .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(3).Row).Value
```

To:

```
For Each e In .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(3).Row)
```

Comment: Hello Shai, thanks for your help. It worked! Next thing is the If statement where I am getting a 424 run time error. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Fiops what line is it ? in this post ?

Comment: @Fiops this is brain new , you just added it 3 minutes ago. trying to get 2 for 1 :) Unfortunately, I can't seem to follow the logic on this, as it is related to another totally different logic regarding the `Dictionary` object. You will need to post a new post, and explain better (with some screen-shots of your data) what you are trying to achieve. It will allow other users to look at  it, and hopefully come up with a solution